# Metamask Faucet

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask

I am trying to request 1 ether for the Ropsten test network using the Metamask Faucet, but not able to request a test ether. [image: Metamask Faucet], any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks
D

Comment: There may be too many requests and yours has been placed in a queue. You can wait or try later. Or use another faucet site.

Comment: Thank you , used another faucet site/network, it is working now